# jQuery ajax var line - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery to call get ajax "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" at line 3.

In here, i removed the original URL due to confidential purpose. but even i remove the csrHost line, the following line also will hit the same error.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
function getCSR(){
    $.ajax ({
        var csrHost = "https://example.com/jsp/csr.jsp?";
        var commonname = '&'+'commonname'+'='+$('#csrName').val().toUpperCase();
        var company = '&'+'org'+'='+$('#csrCom').val().toUpperCase();
        var city = '&'+'locality'+'='+$('#csrCity').val().toUpperCase();
        var state = '&'+'state'+'='+$('#csrState').val().toUpperCase();
        var country = '&'+'country'+'='+$('#csrCountry').val().toUpperCase();
        var OrgUnit = '&'+'commonname'+'='+$('#csrOU').val().toUpperCase();
        var keysize = '&'+'keysize'+'='+2048;
        url: csrHost+commonname+company+city+state+country+OrgUnit+keysize,
        type: "GET",
        //data: {latlng:40.714224,-73.961452}
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(csr){
            var textareaResult = $('#textarea1')

            textareaResult.html(csr)

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `jQuery-slim` you need to use standard `jQuery`. `ajax` is removed from the `jQuery-slim` version.

You need to create the `url` outside of the `ajax` function. It takes an `object` as parameter, but you use `var` inside it.

```
function getCSR() {

    var csrHost = "https://example.com/jsp/csr.jsp?";
    var commonname = '&' + 'commonname' + '=' + $('#csrName').val().toUpperCase();
    var company = '&' + 'org' + '=' + $('#csrCom').val().toUpperCase();
    var city = '&' + 'locality' + '=' + $('#csrCity').val().toUpperCase();
    var state = '&' + 'state' + '=' + $('#csrState').val().toUpperCase();
    var country = '&' + 'country' + '=' + $('#csrCountry').val().toUpperCase();
    var OrgUnit = '&' + 'commonname' + '=' + $('#csrOU').val().toUpperCase();
    var keysize = '&' + 'keysize' + '=' + 2048;

    $.ajax ({
        url: csrHost + commonname + company + city + state + country + OrgUnit + keysize,
        type: "GET",
        //data: { latlng: 40.714224, -73.961452 },
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(csr) {
            var textareaResult = $('#textarea1');
            textareaResult.html(csr)
        }
    })
}
```

You can also try with this approach, which I think is more beautiful.

```
function getCSR() {

    var csrHost = "https://example.com/jsp/csr.jsp?";

    var keyValues = [
      { name: 'commonname', value: $('#csrName').val() },
      { name: 'org', value: $('#csrCom').val() },
      { name: 'locality', value: $('#csrCity').val() },
      { name: 'state', value: $('#csrState').val() },
      { name: 'country', value: $('#csrCountry').val() },
      { name: 'commonname', value: $('#csrOU').val() },
      { name: 'keysize', value: '2048' },
    ];

    var queryString = keyValues.map(item => `${item.name}=${item.value.toUpperCase()}`)
                               .join('&');       

        $.ajax ({
            url: csrHost + queryString,
            type: "GET",
            //data: { latlng: 40.714224, -73.961452 },
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(csr) {
                var textareaResult = $('#textarea1');
                textareaResult.html(csr)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But now i got another error "Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function" from the $.ajax({ line.

Comment: Have you add `jQuery`? To what refers your `$` ?

Comment: End of my html is using <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="script.js"></script>

For my script.js, it just the above jquery code.

Comment: `$.ajax` is removed from the `slim` version. Use standard jQuery

Comment: Thank you so much, it working now.. Although i still got error but i think need to create another post for that..

Answer (score 0):

The Definition of Jquery Ajax function defines as

```
jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] )
```

which means you can supply a url and settings (optional).
you are trying to define a bunch of statements, which are invalid in this context and hence the error. You need to pass in an URL or a settings object as specified by the Spec.
[Jquery Ajax Specification](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

For example in your case  following would be the right way :

```
function getCSR() {

    var csrHost = "https://example.com/jsp/csr.jsp?";
    var commonname = '&' + 'commonname' + '=' + $('#csrName').val().toUpperCase();
    var company = '&' + 'org' + '=' + $('#csrCom').val().toUpperCase();
    var city = '&' + 'locality' + '=' + $('#csrCity').val().toUpperCase();
    var state = '&' + 'state' + '=' + $('#csrState').val().toUpperCase();
    var country = '&' + 'country' + '=' + $('#csrCountry').val().toUpperCase();
    var OrgUnit = '&' + 'commonname' + '=' + $('#csrOU').val().toUpperCase();
    var keysize = '&' + 'keysize' + '=' + 2048;

    $.ajax ({
        url: csrHost + commonname + company + city + state + country + OrgUnit + keysize,
        type: "GET",
        //data: { latlng: 40.714224, -73.961452 },
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(csr) {
            var textareaResult = $('#textarea1');
            textareaResult.html(csr)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extracts the creation of variables from within the ajax function. Like this:

```
function getCSR(){  
    var csrHost = "https://example.com/jsp/csr.jsp?",
        commonname = '&'+'commonname'+'='+$('#csrName').val().toUpperCase(),
        company = '&'+'org'+'='+$('#csrCom').val().toUpperCase(),
        city = '&'+'locality'+'='+$('#csrCity').val().toUpperCase(),
        state = '&'+'state'+'='+$('#csrState').val().toUpperCase(),
        country = '&'+'country'+'='+$('#csrCountry').val().toUpperCase(),
        OrgUnit = '&'+'commonname'+'='+$('#csrOU').val().toUpperCase(),
        keysize = '&'+'keysize'+'='+2048,
        url = csrHost+commonname+company+city+state+country+OrgUnit+keysize
    $.ajax ({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(csr){
            var textareaResult = $('#textarea1')
            textareaResult.html(csr)
        }
    })
}
```

More info about JQuery Ajax function's [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Hiii Actually the problem is , you can not use var inside ajax request ,You can define those variables outside the $.ajax and then use those inside it , it will work.

and just to let you know , you can not use var inside json object :)

```
{
"key":"value"
}
```

This is the correct way of json

```
$.ajax( {    }   )
```

this holds a json object so this can not contain the var.

hope it will clear your doubts :) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCSR(){
    var csrHost = "https://example.com/jsp/csr.jsp";
    var param = {
            commonname: $('#csrName').val().toUpperCase(), 
            org: $('#csrCom').val().toUpperCase(), 
            locality: $('#csrCity').val().toUpperCase(), 
            state: $('#csrState').val().toUpperCase(),
            country: $('#csrCountry').val().toUpperCase(),
            commonname: $('#csrOU').val().toUpperCase(),
            keysize:2048
            };

    $.ajax ({
        url: csrHost,
        type: "GET",
        data: param,
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(csr){
            var textareaResult = $('#textarea1')
            textareaResult.html(csr)
        }
    })
}
```